# How to call an Activity method in an Adapter

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-activity, android-adapter

I'm working on a School Project and i have difficulites on it.

Basicly, I need to press a button and open a Google Map with a marker associated to coordinates.

To open a new MapActivity i use this in MainActivity:

```
fun launchGoogleActivity(latitude : Double, longitude : Double, title: String): Boolean 
{
   val intent = Intent(this, MapsActivity::class.java).apply 
   {
      putExtra("latitude", latitude)
      putExtra("longitude", longitude)
      putExtra("title", title)
   }
   startActivity(intent)
   return true
}
```

In my MapActivity I use this to put the new marker:

```
val extras = intent.extras
val latitude: Double
val longitude: Double
val title: String
latitude = extras?.getString("latitude")?.toDouble()!!
longitude = extras.getString("longitude")?.toDouble()!!
title = extras.getString("name").toString()

val newPoint = LatLng(latitude, longitude)
mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(newPoint).title(title))
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(newPoint))
```

And I have these datas in my Adapter:

```
holder.buttonMap.setOnClickListener 
{
   val latitude = user?.location?.location?.latitude?.toDouble()
   val longitude = user?.location?.location?.longitude?.toDouble()
   val name : String = "Localisation de: " + user?.name?.nom + " " + user?.name?.prenom
}
```

How can i do `launchGoogleActivity(latitude, longitude, name)` in my Adapter ?

Thanks !

Comment: You have to make launchGoogleActivity as a [Companion Object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#companion-objects)

Comment: I tried it but i don't know how it work, my Itent isn't recognized when I create an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass function in your adapter

```
class YourAdapter(private val listener : (Double, Double,String) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>()
```

and in your viewHoler

```
val latitude = user?.location?.location?.latitude?.toDouble()
val longitude = user?.location?.location?.longitude?.toDouble()
val name : String = "Localisation de: " + user?.name?.nom + " " + user?.name?.prenom


holder.buttonMap.setOnClickListener {
   listener(latitude,longitude,name)
}
```

And in your MainActivity where you set the adapter

```
YourAdapter(){latitude: Double, longitude: Double, name: String -> launchMapActivity(latitude,longitude,name)}
```

Comment: And how I call the method in the Fragment ? `private var usersAdapter = UsersAdapter()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to start activity from Adapter.

Inside your activity where you are calling method pass parameter

```
YourAdapter(this)
```

Take context in argument

```
class CategoriesListAdapter(private val context: Context) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() { }
```

then inside your holder.buttonMap.setOnClickListener method :

```
context.startActivity(Intent(context, SubCategoryActivity::class.java)
                        .putExtra(AppConstants.CATEGORY_ID, categoryData.getId())
                        .putExtra(AppConstants.CATEGORY_NAME, categoryData.getName()))
```

Comment: But i need to call the adapter in the fragment :/

Comment: You can call adapter in fragment by calling simple YourAdapter(requireContext)

Answer (score 1):

Add context to your adapter's constructor and set onclicklistener on your button. Add this code inside it.

```
  holder.buttonMap.setOnClickListener {    
  val intent = Intent(context,MapsActivity::class.java).apply {
  putExtra("latitude", latitude)
  putExtra("longitude", longitude)
  putExtra("title", title)}
  context.startActivity(intent)}
```

Comment: How can i get the context in the Fragment when i call the adapter ?

Comment: use requireContext() @EvanSedeno

Answer (score 1):

You can call your functions from activity to your adapter

In your adapter, add an interface class that we will override in your activity.

```
class MarkerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
     var callback: Callback? = null

     inner class ViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
          init {
               holder.buttonMap.setOnClickListener{
                   callback?.onItemClick(user)
               }
          }
     }

     interface Callback {
         fun onItemClick(user: User?)
     }
}
```

then in your activity you just need to implement your adapter's callback

```
class GoogleFragment() : MarkerAdapter.Callback {

    override fun onItemClick(user: User?) {
         val latitude = user?.location?.location?.latitude?.toDouble()
         val longitude = user?.location?.location?.longitude?.toDouble()
         val name : String = "Localisation de: " + user?.name?.nom + " " + user?.name?.prenom
    }
}
```

after adding the code above, initialize the callback property from your adapter in your activity.

```
val adapter = MarkerAdapter()
adapter.callback = this
recylerView.adapter = adapter
```